Is a JPEG file that is missing “ff da” on its header recoverable?
Is a JPEG file that is missing ff da on its header recoverable?
I have a JPEG file that will not display, I've tried putting the file on a hex editor and searching for ff da in attempt to fix the header and nothing shows up.

If the header is incorrect or missing then there's nothing to say that the rest of the file contains valid data at all. Where did this file come from? If it is a file recovered from a drive then it's possible that the data was overwritten and the recovery program only recovered the pointer to the file on disk and not the original data.

From what you've described, the file might not just have a header issue, it could also have damage extending into the actual image data. As someone also pointed out, one way to proceed is to try gluing a header from a known good file from the same camera and settings. But that’s a pretty technical process, and even after that, the image might still need adjustments for color or alignment.
Check the file's entropy to confirm if it even contains usable image data—tools like JPEG Repair Toolkit (mentioned here before) can help analyze that.
If the manual route feels overwhelming, there are specialized recovery tools out there that automate parts of the process. Some might work better for cases like this, where header issues and partial data loss overlap.
